# My categorical variables are not being correctly mapped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, one-hot-encoding

I hope this message finds you well. I have been trying to map categorical variables to their corresponding values since the categorical variables are of large type. However due to error they are not being correctly mapped. My categorical variables are as follows:
#Since now we have gotten rid of null values. We would deal with the categorical columns

```
df["material_spec"].unique()

array(['Material_1', 'Material_0', 'Material_2', 'Material_3',
       'Material_4', 'Material_5', 'Material_6', 'Material_7',
       'Material_8', 'Material_9', 'Material_10', 'Material_11',
       'Material_12', 'Material_13', 'Material_14', 'Material_15',
       'Material_16', 'Material_17', 'Material_18', 'Material_19',
       'Material_20', 'Material_21', 'Material_22', 'Material_23',
       'Material_24', 'Material_25', 'Material_26', 'Material_27',
       'Material_29', 'Material_30', 'Material_31', 'Material_32',
       'Material_33', 'Material_34', 'Material_35', 'Material_36',
       'Material_37', 'Material_38', 'Material_39', 'Material_40',
       'Material_42', 'Material_43', 'Material_44', 'Material_45',
       'Material_47', 'Material_48'], dtype=object)
```

And the code to map is as follows:

```
d = dict()
for i in range(len(df["material_spec"].unique())):
    d.update({f'Material_{i}':i})
```

The resulting output is as follows:

```
{'Material_0': 0, 'Material_1': 1, 'Material_2': 2, 'Material_3': 3, 'Material_4': 4, 'Material_5': 5, 'Material_6': 6, 'Material_7': 7, 'Material_8': 8, 'Material_9': 9, 'Material_10': 10, 'Material_11': 11, 'Material_12': 12, 'Material_13': 13, 'Material_14': 14, 'Material_15': 15, 'Material_16': 16, 'Material_17': 17, 'Material_18': 18, 'Material_19': 19, 'Material_20': 20, 'Material_21': 21, 'Material_22': 22, 'Material_23': 23, 'Material_24': 24, 'Material_25': 25, 'Material_26': 26, 'Material_27': 27, 'Material_28': 28, 'Material_29': 29, 'Material_30': 30, 'Material_31': 31, 'Material_32': 32, 'Material_33': 33, 'Material_34': 34, 'Material_35': 35, 'Material_36': 36, 'Material_37': 37, 'Material_38': 38, 'Material_39': 39, 'Material_40': 40, 'Material_41': 41, 'Material_42': 42, 'Material_43': 43, 'Material_44': 44}
```

It is missing out the last three variables of 45,47 and 48. I know when I use len(material_spec) the total amounts to 44 thats why it is only mapping till 44 variables but is there any way to further improve it. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have an inconsistency between your unique Material_ array and that fact that you are indexing and assuming that all numbers in the range are present in you unique array.  Your `df["material_spec"].unique()` output is missing Material_ 28, 41 and 46.  You are then indexing by length assuming that they are all numerically present so it appears to drop at the end.  Numerically it looks like you should have 49 in the list but only really have 46.  Your dictionary has 45 entries (0-based).  Though can't explain why that is one-off from the 46 unique.

When I run your code I get 46 entries in both.  Though I cannot duplicate the `.unique()` call since I do not have your original data.

You could just use the actual unique values themselves by doing:

```
{e: int(e.split('_')[1]) for e in df["material_spec"].unique()}

{'Material_0': 0,
 'Material_1': 1,
 'Material_2': 2,
 'Material_3': 3,
 'Material_4': 4,
 'Material_5': 5,
 'Material_6': 6,
 'Material_7': 7,
 'Material_8': 8,
 'Material_9': 9,
 'Material_10': 10,
 'Material_11': 11,
 'Material_12': 12,
    ...
 'Material_39': 39,
 'Material_40': 40,
 'Material_42': 42,
 'Material_43': 43,
 'Material_44': 44,
 'Material_45': 45,
 'Material_47': 47,
 'Material_48': 48}
```

Notice that the keys in this output dictionary contains no 41 and 46 which matches the input unique keys.

Comment: Can I also use label encoder to encode these values. Will it be a right approach?

Comment: @Sam For sure!  Way easier that rolling your own.  Though you are not guaranteed that, for example, Material_21 will be encoded as 21.  In fact it probably won't be.

Comment: But since there is probably no ordinal dependency (Material_21 is better than Material_0) then that shouldn't matter.

Comment: the above code that you wrote is giving an error "'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: What does this return?  `df["material_spec"].dtype`. Since `df["material_spec"].dtype` should not be containing INTs.  I just tested the code again and it worked for me - with `df["material_spec"]` containing strings (`Material_nn`)

Comment: Could `df["material_spec"]` have accidentally contained label-encoded integers?  The error indicates that it contained integers when the code was run.

Comment: The dtype of material_spec is object

Comment: Thanks it worked now. Maybe it was glitch from my side